# Protractor times out waiting for sync with page when using $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-resource, protractor

I'm testing Protractor with a small AngularJS app.

This is the test:

```
describe('Testing Protractor', function() {
  var draftList;

  it('should count the number of drafts', function() {
    browser.get('#/');
    draftList = element.all(by.repeater('newsletter in drafts'));
    expect(draftList.count()).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
  controller('DraftsCtrl', ['$scope', 'Draft', function($scope, Draft) {
    $scope.drafts = Draft.query();
}])
```

Draft service:

```
angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource']).
  factory('Draft', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
      return $resource('api/drafts/:id')
    }])
```

Running this test using Protractor results in the following error:

```
Error: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds
```

However, if in the controller I change this line:

```
$scope.drafts = Draft.query();
```

to this:

```
$scope.drafts = [];
```

The test fails as expected, but more importantly: it does not time out.

With query() enabled, both when running the app manually in a browser and when looking at the browser window opened by Protractor, the data returned by the API is correctly displayed by a repeater.

Why is Protractor not able to synchronize with the page when the service is communicating with the API?

AngularJS is v1.2.0-rc3. Protractor is v0.12.0.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/49), but there is a temporary workaround. Set `ptor.ignoreSynchronization = true`.

For example:

```
describe('Testing Protractor', function() {
  var draftList;
  var ptor;

  beforeEach(function() {
    ptor = protractor.getInstance();
    ptor.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  });

  it('should count the number of drafts', function() {
    ptor.get('#/');
    draftList = element.all(by.repeater('newsletter in drafts'));
    expect(draftList.count()).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out later and let you know whether it worked. I actually did read that GitHub issue before posting here, but I was under the impression that the workaround is only required when polling an API at regular intervals which my test app is not doing. It only sends the API request once, when the controller is initialized.

Comment: This was indeed the correct solution. Since Protractor 0.12.0 exposes the instance of Protractor as `browser`, it was enough to just add `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` before `element.all(by.repeater(' ... '));`.

Comment: protractor.getInstance() had been unused (replaced by global browser in v0.12.0) and is [now removed](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes).

Answer (score 3):

`browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` worked out for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Protractor 3.3.0  and to get this to work in my test I had to defer the ignore synchronisation until after I had done the setup.

So in my beforeEach I call my action:

```
var searchBox = element(by.css('#inpt_search'));
searchBox.sendKeys('test');
```

I then have to wait for the mock backend to populate the view (I'm not happy about these `sleep` calls so if anyone has a better way of doing this please comment, I can't get `expectedConditions.presenceOf` to work as it's part of the same bug) using `browser.sleep(500)`.
Then in the test I set `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true` which unblocks whatever is blocked and sees the browser content.

```
describe('standard search', function (){
    beforeEach(function (){
        openApp();
        var searchBox = element(by.css('#inpt_search'));
        searchBox.sendKeys('test');
        browser.sleep(500);
    });
    it('should work or summat', function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        var fileItems = element.all(by.repeater('item in list'));
        expect(fileItems.count()).toEqual(50);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `browser.ignoreSynchronization`, use `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(*boolean*)`. `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)` sets `browser.ignoreSynchronization` to `true`, `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true)` sets `browser.ignoreSynchronization` to `false`.

you can also include this as part of your test suites' config file:

```
onPrepare: function () {
    'use strict';
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
}
```