# Protractor : Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: {}

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Okay, I have an angular app in which there are directives and some other normal html element.
This directive is interesting, as it uses RaphaelJs to create custom graphics. This directive also uses require js to load dependecies( like raphel.js). Every thing works fine :)

Now the hard part. I want to write some E2E test cases. I want to select the svg elements that are created by directive and check some attributes values.

So in the browser(Chrome) console, I type $('tspan'), I see a host of tspans elements being returned by the simple css selector.

sample tspan

```
<tspan dy="7" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Somevalue</tspan>
```

When I write the same query in E2E sheets

```
 var svgElement = $('tspan')[0];
 console.log(svgElement);
```

It logs following :

```
{ click: [Function],
  sendKeys: [Function],
  getTagName: [Function],
  getCssValue: [Function],
  getAttribute: [Function],
  getText: [Function],
  getSize: [Function],
  getLocation: [Function],
  isEnabled: [Function],
  isSelected: [Function],
  submit: [Function],
  clear: [Function],
  isDisplayed: [Function],
  getOuterHtml: [Function],
  getInnerHtml: [Function],
  findElements: [Function],
  isElementPresent: [Function],
  evaluate: [Function],
  '$$': [Function],
  findElement: [Function],
  '$': [Function],
  find: [Function],
  isPresent: [Function] }
```

When I try to access the getText method on the same element, I get the

```
 var svgElement = $('tspan');
    console.log(svgElement.getText());

C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\seleniu
m-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1549
      throw error;
            ^
Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: {}
```

Can not understand the root cause. Can anybody help ?

Comment: try adding "browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;" (or "ptor.ignoreSynchronization = true;") befor running your first test.

Answer (score 2):

I just learned the hard way that protractor and angular versions are tightly coupled.

Using angular 1.2.16 and Protractor 0.23.1 resulted in the error you have - seems that an internal angular API has changed. (the test in protractor is attempting to execute:

```
  angular.element(el).injector().get('$browser').notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(callback);
```

and injector() didn't exist on an element in 1.2.16.. hence my failure)

In my case, I'm testing updating to angular 1.3-beta.10, which seems to result in a more copacetic world (at least as protractor 0.23.1 has to do with)

Answer (score 0):

I'd think you would get a different error if this was the issue but I think you may need to format getText() as shown below because it uses a promise.

```
var svgElement = $('tspan');
svgElement.getText().then(function (text){
   console.log(text);
}
```

Are any of your tests running? I only had the "Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: {}" because ng-app wasn't on the body tag, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059943/running-into-error-while-waiting-for-protractor-to-sync-with-the-page-with-basic) for solution.