# Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "angular could not be found on the window"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I am getting the following error message for my protractor test scripts. The scripts were running fine until I updated my projects for a few of the scripts. The scripts run and the error is thrown at the end. I have tried `browser.waitForAngular();` and `browser.sleep()` with no success.

> Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page:
>   "angular could not be found on the window"   Stack:
>       Error: Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "angular could not be found on the window"
>           at /Users/faizul/WebstormProjects/canary/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:104:16
>           at /Users/faizul/WebstormProjects/canary/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1582:15
>           at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_
>   (/Users/faizul/WebstormProjects/canary/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1654:20)
>           at notify (/Users/faizul/WebstormProjects/canary/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:465:12)

Comment: Is it an angular application under test?

Comment: see the first answer here - I assume that will fix it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059943/running-into-error-while-waiting-for-protractor-to-sync-with-the-page-with-basic

Answer (score 2):

If changing the `rootElement` does not work by itself, try adding `framework: 'jasmine2'` to `exports.config` in your Protractor configuration file.  I stumbled upon that earlier while trying to figure out the problem. Changing only the `rootElement` did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

add `framework: 'jasmine2'` to your conf.js file . more info here [#1978](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1978)