# Error while waiting for the protractor to sync with the page: "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"

Tags: angularjs, testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor, end-to-end

My test target page has SSO integrated login. Once I hit the page, SSO integrated windows authentication will occur then directed to home page.

I tried to turn Sync off and it works for first test to check title but for second test, it will return error unable to locate element and when I turn on Sync, it will return out of sync error and undefined error.

```
describe('Test area to ', function () {

var menuObjects = require('../page/MenuObjects.js');

it('Verify Page Title', function () {
    menuObjects.setSyncOff(); 
    browser.get('/home/');
    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Home');
    browser.driver.sleep(3000);
});

it('Navigate ', function () {
    menuObjects.setSyncOn();
    menuObjects.menuButton.click();        
});
});
```

Error message for Navigate - with menuObjects.setSyncOn();

> Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"

Error message for Navigate - with menuObjects.setSyncOff();

> NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.id("menu-link")

`ng-app` is included in div within body:

```
<body style="width: 100%">
<div class="frame" style="width: 100%">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 100%">
        <div class="" style="width: 100%">
            <div style="width: 100%">
                <!--_AngularBaseLayout: BEGIN-->                    

<div ng-app="myHomeApp" ng-cloak class="ng-cloak">
     <div ng-view id="ng-view"> </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Where is the element that is supposed to have the id `menu-link`? Assuming your menuObjects.setSyncOn is toggling `browser.ignoreSynchronization`, try accessing webdriver directly while it is off via `browser.driver.get`.

Comment: Yes, I was setting ignoreSynchronization true false. id `menu-link` is located at  11th div tag from body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ng-app` is not defined on `html` or `body`, you need to let `protractor` know about it by setting [`rootElement` configuration setting](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/9891d430aff477c5feb80ae01b48356866820132/spec/altRootConf.js):

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: env.seleniumAddress,

  baseUrl: env.baseUrl,

  ...

  // Selector for the element housing the angular app.
  rootElement: 'div#nested-ng-app'
};
```

This would make playing around with switching syncing on and off not necessary - protractor would wait for angular "to settle down" before proceeding to the further test execution.

---

If this doesn't help with `NoSuchElementError` error, you can explicitly wait for the element to become present with the help of [`presenceOf` "Expected Condition"](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.presenceOf):

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

var elm = browser.wait(EC.presenceOf($('#menu-link')), 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks @alecxe. Getting close. I did found post with rootElement and tried it but for some reason, it didn't work and now, seems to be working when I put it below baseUrl. In my current Navigate Test, I have updated below code and seems to be clicking but protractor is still reporting element not visible   `browser.waitForAngular();`    `var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;`  `browser.wait(EC.presenceOf($('#menu-link')), 5000);`  `menuObjects.menuButton.click().then(function() {`  `menuObjects.firstButton.click();  `  `});`

Comment: Btw, I've added rootElement: 'div#nested-ng-app' and still using syncing off. Otherwise, sync page error will still appear.

Comment: looks like issue is definitely with rootElement, I also tried this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059943/running-into-error-while-waiting-for-protractor-to-sync-with-the-page-with-basic) but doesn't seems to be working :(

Comment: @user2388556 thanks, `div#nested-ng-app` was an example locator, you need to use your own locator to get to the element where `ng-app` is defined.

Comment: Yeah, I did try following `div#nested-myHomeApp`, `div#nested-ng-cloak`, `.ng-cloak`, `#ng-cloak` and `div#ng-cloak` but for some reason, I still need to set sync off :(

Comment: Ok, issue resolved now. Issue with locator and I have updated [ng-app] for rootElement to locate attribute and works perfectly fine now. Sync on off were taken and no issue with windows integrated authentication as well. Thanks again for your help! @alecxe