# issues while running protractor tests

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I am new to Protractor . Here is my config file

`config`:

```
exports.config = {
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
},

specs: ['./protractor-tests/*.js'],

jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true
}
}
```

Here I have a scenario where I am testing the login where the user login through outlook and when click on login it redirects to home page.

Login test :

```
exports.login = function() {
describe('Login Test', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        browser.get('http://domain/login');
    });
    afterEach(function() {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
    });
    it('It should redirect to outlook for auth', function() {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        var currentUrl;
        browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
            currentUrl = url;
        }).then(function() {
            browser.wait(function() {
                return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
                    return url !== currentUrl;
                });
            });
        }).then(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                var userName = element(By.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/header/div[1]/section/div[2]/apt-user-profile/div/div/button[1]/span/span'));
                if (userName)
                    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('http://domain/home');
                else
                    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('https://login.microsoftonline.com');
            }, 10000);


        });
    });

    it('It should login into the application and display user as Tom White', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            browser.driver.findElement(by.id('cred_userid_inputtext')).sendKeys('tomwhite@gmail.com');
            browser.driver.findElement(by.id('cred_password_inputtext')).sendKeys('****');
            browser.driver.findElement(by.id('cred_sign_in_button')).click();
            var userName = element(By.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/header/div[1]/section/div[2]/apt-user-profile/div/div/button[1]/span/span'));
            expect(userName.getText()).toEqual('Hello Tom White');
        }, 10000);
    });

});
}
```

These test cases are actually working fine, but when in home page, I need to also click on an element that redirects me to some other page it is failing with error

```
  Failed: javascript error: document unloaded while waiting for result
```

home tests:

```
 var loginPage = require('./loginTest.js');

describe('Home Test', function() {
    loginPage.login();
    it('It should click product', function() {

            var productMenu = element(By.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/headerdiv[1]/section/div[1]/apt-nav-bar/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a/span'));
            productMenu.click();
            expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).not.toEqual('http://domain/home');
            expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('http://domain/products');


        })

});
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is due to absence of waiting for the page to do something. You can implement an explicit wait using the `ExpectionConditions` functionality provided by Protractor. Here is the link from the [API](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions).

A dirty solution is to use a `sleep()` method so that the execution is paused for a certain period of time, say 5 seconds. So you can try `browser.sleep(5000)`, which should do away with the error. However, this is not a good solution.

Edit 1 : The `rootElement` param of the `exports.config` object defined in your protractor configuration file must match the element containing your `ng-app` directive.

In your protractor-conf.js, please add

```
rootElement: '.my-app',
```

when your HTML is:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" class="my-app">
```

Source : [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059943/running-into-error-while-waiting-for-protractor-to-sync-with-the-page-with-basic).

Comment: if i do browser.sleep(5000)
I m getting the error  Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "window.angular is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `login` function outside of `it` or "before" or "after" functions which are under the Protractor's control flow. Move your `loginPage.login();` call to `beforeEach()` or `beforeAll()`:

```
describe('Home Test', function() {
    beforeEach(function () {
        loginPage.login();
    });

    it('It should click product', function() {
        var productMenu = element(By.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/headerdiv[1]/section/div[1]/apt-nav-bar/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a/span'));
        productMenu.click();
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).not.toEqual('http://domain/home');
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('http://domain/products');
    })
});
```