# Protractor beforeAll() not running

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I was trying to run a test that had worked the day before and got an error message saying
`- Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "window.angular is undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"`

I added a `console.log("hi")` in one of my `beforeAll()` calls and there was no output in the console, so I suspect the error is that `beforeAll()` is not invoked for some reason.

I'm using the latest jasmine framework in my `conf` file and some of my tests run when I don't include the `beforeAll()`, but not all of them. This test was working fine yesterday and I ran it again today without any changes, so I'm not sure what the problem might be. Does anyone else know?

I'll include my conf.js file and part of the test I'm running.

My conf.js file

```
let SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;
exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    directConnect: true,
    allScriptsTimeout: 50000,
    rootElement: 'html',
    untrackOutstandingTimeouts: true,

//    suites: {
      //HealthCheck: './specs/Health Check/**.js',
      //ContectCheck: './specs/Content Check/**.js',
//    },

    specs: [
      //  'specs/submitFeedback.js',
      'specs/createTeacherAndStudentOld.js',
      //  'specs/temp.js',
      //  'specs/manipTeste.js',
    ],
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    },
    params: {
        screenWidth: 1920,
        screenHeight: 1080,
        siteURL: 'https://alpha.khmath.com',
        marketingSiteURL: 'https://knowledgehook.com',
        portalUsername: '',
        portalPassword: '',
        classRedemptionCode: 'testcode1',
        contentCheckCourse: 'Grade 9 Academic',
        homeWorkCourse: 'Grade 9 Applied',
        gameShowCourse: 'Grade 9 Applied',
        term: '2016-2017 Full Year',
        gameShowSiteUrl: 'https://alpha.khmath.com/play'
    },
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 7200000,
        print: function() {}
    },
    onPrepare: function () {

        global.helper = require('./helper.js');
        global.completeQuestionHelper = require('./pages/student/completeQuestionHelper.js');

        global.fs = require('fs');
        global.https = require('https');
        global.LoginPage = require('./pages/loginPage.js');
        global.RegistrationPage = require('./pages/registrationPage.js');

        global.TeacherGameShowPage = require('./pages/teacher/teacherGameShowPage.js');
        global.TeacherHomePage = require('./pages/teacher/teacherHomePage.js');
        global.TeacherMissionPage = require('./pages/teacher/teacherMissionPage.js');
        global.TeacherPurchasePage = require('./pages/teacher/teacherPurchasePage.js');
        global.TeacherStudentsPage = require('./pages/teacher/teacherStudentsPage.js');
        global.TeacherStudentSummaryPage = require('./pages/teacher/teacherStudentSummaryPage.js');
        global.TeacherReportPage = require('./pages/teacher/teacherReportPage.js');

        global.StudentHomePage = require('./pages/student/studentHomePage.js');
        global.StudentAllSkillsPage = require('./pages/student/studentAllSkillsPage.js');
        global.StudentSkillPage = require('./pages/student/studentSkillPage.js');
        global.StudentGameplayPage = require('./pages/student/studentGameplayPage.js');
        global.StudentMissionPage = require('./pages/student/studentMissionPage.js');
        global.StudentPortfolioPage = require('./pages/student/StudentPortfolioPage.js');

        global.GameShowStudentGameplayPage = require('./pages/gameshow/gameShowStudentGameplayPage.js');
        global.GameShowStudentRegistrationPage = require('./pages/gameshow/gameShowStudentRegistrationPage.js');
        global.GameShowTeacherGameplayPage = require('./pages/gameshow/gameShowTeacherGameplayPage.js');


        global.loginPage = new LoginPage(browser);
        global.registrationPage = new RegistrationPage(browser);

        global.teacherGameShowPage = new TeacherGameShowPage(browser);
        global.teacherHomePage = new TeacherHomePage(browser);
        global.teacherMissionPage = new TeacherMissionPage(browser);
        global.teacherPurchasePage = new TeacherPurchasePage(browser);
        global.teacherStudentsPage = new TeacherStudentsPage(browser);
        global.teacherStudentSummaryPage = new TeacherStudentSummaryPage(browser);
        global.teacherReportPage = new TeacherReportPage(browser);

        global.studentHomePage = new StudentHomePage(browser);
        global.studentAllSkillsPage = new StudentAllSkillsPage(browser);
        global.studentSkillPage = new StudentSkillPage(browser);
        global.studentGameplayPage = new StudentGameplayPage(browser);
        global.studentMissionPage = new StudentMissionPage(browser);
        global.studentPortfolioPage = new StudentPortfolioPage(browser);

        global.gameShowStudentGameplayPage = new GameShowStudentGameplayPage(browser);
        global.gameShowStudentRegistrationPage = new GameShowStudentRegistrationPage(browser);
        global.gameShowTeacherGameplayPage = new GameShowTeacherGameplayPage(browser);

        global.EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
          spec: {
            displayStacktrace: true
          },
          colors: {
            enabled: false,
          },
          prefixes: {
            successful: "O ",
            failed: "X ",
          },
        }));
    },
};
```

My spec file

```
  beforeAll(function () {
      console.log('hi');
      helper.setBrowserParams(browser);
      browser.get(browser.params.siteURL);
    });

    it('should register a teacher and create a premium class', function () {
        //Click Register
        loginPage.registerBtn.click();

        ...
```

`

Comment: Check this out - [Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059943/running-into-error-while-waiting-for-protractor-to-sync-with-the-page-with-basic)